# What is Wall clock in maven build

Tags: java, maven, build

When I build my project using threads

i.e `mvn -T 4 install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

I am getting like

```
Total Time: 10:17.623s (Wall Clock)
```

What is meant by Wall clock here? When I build normally I am not getting that word. I searched, but I am unable to find the information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default (without `-T 4`), Maven builds all modules sequentially rather than in parallel. So you only have one process, which (in your example) takes 40s.

You start the build with 4 threads, so the total time of 40s gets divided by 4 threads, so each thread runs for 10s.

The total CPU time stays the same (40s), but the time that passed for YOU is only 10s + some overhead for parallelization. It's the time that you see when you look on your clock on the wall, therefore it's called **Wall-Clock time**.